# how to work with dynamic argument (urls) in Observable.forkJoin()

Tags: angular, rxjs

SO I love forkJoin, basically the replacement of Promise.all, but I can't figure how to feed it a dynamic list as in:

```
Observable.forkJoin(
        this.http.get('/app/books.json').map((res:Response) => res.json()),
        this.http.get('/app/movies.json').map((res:Response) => res.json())
    ).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.books = data[0]
        this.movies = data[1]
      },
      err => console.error(err)
    );
```

only that I need to create the http.gets at runtime (the URLs will be different, destinations and total URLs generated all will be dynamic), tried to pass a config object but it didn't like it...

tx for reading,

Sean.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[forkJoin](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/forkjoin.md) takes first argument as

> args (Arguments | Array): An array or arguments of Observable sequences or Promises to collect the last elements for.

So, you can simply pass it an array of observables . [Here is a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/nU720iSccTicyC2Cfrsn?p=preview)

```
let observables = [
  this.http.get('/app/books.json').map((res:Response) => res.json()),
  this.http.get('/app/movies.json').map((res:Response) => res.json())
];

Observable.forkJoin(observables).subscribe(
   data => {
        this.books = data[0]
        this.movies = data[1]
   },
   err => console.error(err)
);
```

Comment: one thing that seems to be an issue is that I don't get the network err of the reason a failed call... so the err has just 200 and OK replies and no info on failed calls... any way to get back more details on failed calls? tx

Comment: @born2net If you want the actual response body from the server. you can get it as a text from `error._body` . The actual error is a [response object](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/Response-class.html). It has property `error.status` and `error.statusText`. `status` is the status code, `statusText` is a text description of the status code as in [rfc2616](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-6.1.1). Although, `statusText` is not yet properly implemented.

Comment: Tried the same approach for POST requests, URLs are getting called, but the params are not being sent.

Comment: @anirudh please put the code on a new question and let me know here and I will take a look at it

Answer (score 1):

I landed here looking for a way to identify the results of a dynamically assembled group of observables. If I pass an array of observables, I can't know which result will be at which index because the number of and order of observables in the array is unknown.

Since RxJS 6.5+, you can pass an object instead of an array into ForkJoin, where the key will identify the observable, and the value of the key is the observable (known as a dictionary).

```js
// use some logic to dynamically assemble dictionary
const dictionary = {};

if (shouldGetBooks) {
   dictionary.books = this.http.get("/app/books.json");
}
if (shouldGetMovies) {
   dictionary.movies = this.http.get("/app/movies.json");
}

forkJoin(dictionary).subscribe((results) => {
   console.log(results); // { books: booksJson, movies: moviesJson }
});
```

Now the results are easily identifiable by key.